# Google Apps Admin Script App | Forwarding Non-Admin Emails

Tags: google-apps-script

I was wondering Script Apps has the ability for a Google Apps domain to influence non-admin accounts.

Example: 
I want to forward the email address of a club member to a backup email address without having to log in to the account. The account rolls from a new person from year to year (school organization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Apps Email Setting API for forwarding the mails of your Google Apps Users. I have successfully implemented it earlier using UrlFetchApp and oAuth.
Here are few reference links
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/#manage_forwarding_settings 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlfetch